# Not able to autowire a bean using constructor in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Im new to spring. I'm trying to autowire a bean using constructor using spring. Here is the code

```
<bean id="location" class="com.ibm.spring.Location">
    <constructor-arg name="pincode" value="110976"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="address" class="com.ibm.spring.Address">
    <property name="id" value="2"></property>
    <property name="street" value="shahjahan"></property>
</bean>
```

### location class

```
public class Location {

private Address address;
private String pincode;



public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Autowired
public Location(Address address, String pincode) {
    super();
    this.address = address;
    this.pincode = pincode;
}

public void getTotalAddress() {
    System.out.println(this.pincode + "::"+this.address);
}

}
```

### Address class

```
public class Address {

private int id;
private String street;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = "Kkp";
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address [id=" + id + ", street=" + street + "]";
}
```

### Tester

```
 public class SpringTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String configLoc = "com/ibm/spring/config/applicationContext.xml";
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLoc);
    Location l = (Location) ctx.getBean("location");
    l.getTotalAddress();

}

}
```

I'm setting one of the field value through constructor arg. and class should be injected.  WHat could be the problem here?

The error log says

```
Error creating bean with name 'location' defined in class path resource [com/ibm/spring/config/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [com.ibm.spring.Address] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
```

Comment: Did you tried add @Autowired before 
private Address address

Comment: @Autowired is not required for address. Because it will automatically detect. In the constructor arg, I havent passed it. Its working now. Th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Location has two arguments so:

```
<bean id="location" class="com.ibm.spring.Location">
    <constructor-arg name="pincode" value="110976"></constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg ref="address"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Exactly. Right..:)